# mongodb find where columns of arrays don't match

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, find

i am looking for a possible solution to find results from a mongodb collection where two columns of arrays **don't** hold the same entries.
Something like this:

Message DB structure

```
{
 id: ObjectId,
 title: String,
 body: String,
 recipients: [{ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
 visualized_by: [{ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
}
```

when a User visualizes the message his id gets stored in the visualized_by column

Now, from an admin panel I want to visualize only the messages that were not seen by all the recipients like this:

```
Message.find({recipients: {$each: {$nin: "$visualized_by"}}})
```

OR

```
Message.find({$where: {recipients: {$each: {$nin: this.visualized_by}}}})
```

But it does not work of course.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!